# How to measure the success and percent accuracy of an image detection algorithm?

Tags: image, detection

Does anyone know how to properly quantify the success of an image detection algorithm? How do you combine the 2 sources of error? since one source is the number of objects that the algorithm failed to detect and the other is the number of false positives that the algorithm misidentified as the object.

So if for example there were 574 objects in the image but the algorithm only detected 540 of them while producing 113 false positives, how do I get the percent accuracy?

Answer (score 7):

You can calculate what is know as the **F<sub>1</sub> Score** (sometimes just F Score) by first calculating the *precision* and *recall* performance of your algorithm.

The **precision** is the number of *true positives* divided by the number of *predicted positives*, where *predicted positives = (true positives + false positives)*.

The **recall** is the number of *true positives* divided by the number of *actual positives*, where *actual positives = (true positives + false negatives)*.

In other words, **precision** means, "Of all objects where we detected a match, what fraction actually does match?" And **recall** means "Of all objects that actually match, what fraction did we correctly detect as matching?".

Having calculated precision, **P**, and recall, **R**, the **F<sub>1</sub> Score** is **2 * (PR / (P + R))** and gives you a single metric - between 0 and 1 - with which to compare the performance of different algorithms.

The **F<sub>1</sub> Score** is a statistical measure used, among other applications, in machine learning. You can read more about it in [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score).

Comment: There is a nice visual explanation for Precision and Recall on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall

Comment: And my attempt to write its function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271603/how-to-categorize-true-negatives-in-sliding-window-object-detection/42267069#42267069

Answer (score -1):

Here are some measures/metrics that you can use to evaluate your model for image segmentation (or object detection:

- F1 Score
- Dice
- Shape similarity

All of the three are described in this [page of a segmentation challenge](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/dcs/research/tia/glascontest/evaluation/)

Comment: Dice and shape similarity don't apply to object detection.